# C# equivalent enums for TwinCAT Data types

Tags: twincat-ads-.net

Do I need to write the enums for the TwinCAT data types? Or they exist somewhere and I just can't find them?

Example: there is a data type called [`MC_HomingMode`](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclibmc2/458458379.html&id=), which defines how to perform homing. I want to control it VIA ADS, so I need an enum for it. Couldn't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well it apears there is no such thing. In my case, the TwinCAT types I needed, I made them in C# by my self.